# How to match objects in groovy script irrespective of case

Tags: groovy, soapui

Rest Response

```
<Carlist>
<Car>
<Car Name = 'Santro'/>
</Car>
</Carlist>
```

JDBC response

```
<Row number =1>
<CarName>SANTRO</CarName>
</Row>
```

Is there way to compare these two responses using groovy Script.I tried   using groovy script using toUpperCase in gpath but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Also is that XML right for the rest response?

Answer (score 0):

In the Java API there is a ready-made method for this: `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`. It is, of course, ready to use in Groovy as well:

```
// assuming variables restCarName and jdbcCarName
boolean matches = restCarName.equalsIgnoreCase(jdbcCarName)
```

Of course, if `restCarName` is `null`, then this will throw a `NullPointerException`, but you can work around that too with the Groovy elvis operator (`?:`) and the `null`-safe member token (`?.`):

```
boolean matches = restCarName == jdbcCarName ?: restCarName?.equalsIgnoreCase(jdbcCarName)
```

To wit, if exact equality fails (including `null == null`) then try ignoring case (with `null` (false) result if `restCarName` is null).